# Empty typo3conf directory

Tags: typo3

I made a website with Typo3 12 and everything works fine, but after finishing it I found out that the public/typo3conf/ directory is empty.
I want to host my website and think that it will make problems in the future.
What files do I need in this directory?

If you need further informations please ask me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TYPO3 12 extensions have been moved to the `vendor` directory and settings to `config/system`. For more information see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/DirectoryStructure/Index.html